# Class managing queuing updates from another thread, Version 2

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, concurrency

This is an updated version of: [Class to manage updates coming in from another thread](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/102626/25077)

> Managing updates from other threads into Swing is a [hard problem.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/295230/why-is-it-the-callers-responsibility-to-ensure-thread-safety-in-gui-programming) In MVC design, if you don't want to have the Presenter be responsible for Thread safety, you can end up with deadlock issues, and also too many little tasks getting started; not great.
>
> I have written a class designed to manage these updates in the view so that the Presenter is not coupled with the View's threading model. It loads them all into a queue, and then, if a new update is added, it processes the entire queue in case too many updates have come too quickly.

Changes:

- I removed the race condition, I believe
- Removed the need for checking for `InterruptedException`, and therefore a `LOG` in this class
- Added a lock to ensure that all updates are properly processed
- Removed visibility of `Runnable` by making it an inner class
- changed name of `setObject` to `postUpdate`
- Removed unnecessary constructor
- Other minor cosmetic changes

Here's the result:

```
public abstract class SwingUpdater<E> {
    private final LinkedBlockingQueue<E> updates = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();;
    private final AtomicBoolean updating = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public final void postUpdate(E object) {
        updates.add(object);
        synchronized(updating) {
            if (!updating.getAndSet(true)) {
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new SwingUpdaterRunnable());
            }
        }
    }

    private class SwingUpdaterRunnable implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Deque<E> pending = new LinkedList<>();

            do {
                updates.drainTo(pending);

                while (!pending.isEmpty()) {
                    doTask(pending.removeFirst());
                }
            } while (!atomicCheckCanStop());
        }
        
        private boolean atomicCheckCanStop() {
            synchronized(updating) {
                boolean isEmpty = updates.isEmpty();
                if(isEmpty) {
                    updating.set(false);
                }
                return isEmpty;
            }
        }
    }

    protected abstract void doTask(E update);
}
```

For convenience, here's the sample `main` again to demonstrate this class in action:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingUpdaterExample {
    private final JFrame testFrame;
    private final JPanel contentPane;
    private final JTextPane textPane;
    private int updateCount;
    
    private final SwingUpdater<String> updater = new SwingUpdater<String>() {
        @Override
        protected void doTask(String update) {
            String oldText = textPane.getText();
            textPane.setText(oldText + ((updateCount & 3) == 0 ? System.lineSeparator() : "\t") + update);
            updateCount++;
        }
    };
    
    public SwingUpdaterExample() {
        textPane = new JTextPane();
        
        contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.add(textPane);
        
        testFrame = new JFrame("ExampleFrame");
        testFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        testFrame.setSize(500,800);
        testFrame.setContentPane(contentPane);
    }
    
    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        testFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public void appendText(String string) {
        updater.postUpdate(string);
    }
    
    public static class ExampleTask implements Runnable {
        private final String name;
        private final SwingUpdaterExample view;
        
        public ExampleTask(String name, SwingUpdaterExample view) {
            this.name = name;
            this.view = view;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Random r = new Random();
            for(int counter = 0; counter < 15; counter++) {
                if(r.nextDouble() < 0.3) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000 + r.nextInt(4000));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                view.appendText(name + " - " + counter);    
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final SwingUpdaterExample frame = new SwingUpdaterExample();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            
        });
        
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            ExampleTask task = new ExampleTask("Task" + i, frame);
            service.submit(task);
        }
        
        service.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should you synchronize on an `AtomicBoolean`?

Answer (score 4):

Synchronization *and* atomic boolean is overkill. Especially since you only access the boolean inside the synchronized blocks. Choose one or the other.

Draining to a `LinkedList` and then `removeFirst` each element is less efficient than reserving enough space in a `ArrayList`, draining to it and iterating over it.

```
do {
    ArrayList<E> pending = new ArrayList<E>(updates.size()+3);
    updates.drainTo(pending);

    for(E task : pending){
        doTask(task);
    }

} while (!atomicCheckCanStop());
```

---

Having said all that the Java devs have solved this problem before and created [sun.swing.AccumulativeRunnable](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/swing/AccumulativeRunnable.html) which is used by `SwingWorker` for it's [publish](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#publish(V...))->[process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#process(java.util.List)) mechanism and grouping the `setProgress()` calls into 1 event. There they don't bother with checking the queue again after draining it.